# Why can't I use "%s" format value in the Wordpress function checked?

Tags: php, settings-api

I try to safe a checkbox with the Wordpress settings API.
For that I use the `checked()` function.
First I make my field with `add_settings_field()` and pass a view parameters in an array to the callback function.

In the callback function of my field I make an output with

```
printf(
        '<input type="checkbox" id="%2$s" name="%1$s[%2$s]" '. checked("on", '%3$s').'
         <label for="%2$s">%4$s</label>
         <hr /> ',
        $args['option_name'],
        $args['name'],
        $args['value'],
        $args['description']    
    );
```

Now normally the checkbox should be saved. **BUT** the check-function doesn't work.

When I print the parameter value `%3$s` then the value is "**on**" if the field is checked and **nothing** if the field is not checked.
But the check-function never triggers even if `%3$s` is "**on**".

Only if I insert the "on" string `checked("on", 'on')`  directly it returns checked.

*So my question is: Why I can't use `%3$s` in the checked function?*

Comment: `checked()` prints the value immediately, before even `printf()` is finished. Look at the third parameter.

Comment: @toscho And how can I change it if I want that something changes ? I already tried the third param with false and true, but nothing changed.

Comment: `checked("on", '%3$s', false)` is evaluated first, the returned string is passed to `printf()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the order of operations means you're passing that variable into your checked function before the printf function is even being run, which is what's parsing the enumerated variables.

Here's a possible solution haven't tested it though:

```
printf(
    '<input type="checkbox" id="%2$s" name="%1$s[%2$s]" %3$s)'.
    '<label for="%2$s">%4$s</label>' .
    '<hr />',
    $args['option_name'],
    $args['name'],
    checked("on", $args['value'], false ),
    $args['description']    
);
```

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, but what do I have to change that it works ?

Comment: Do I have to access the args array directly like args[1]? Is there no other way that I can use %3$s?

Comment: Did you try running the variable on your variables being passed?  I'll edit my answer to reflect what I'm talking about, but I won't be able to test it.

Comment: I changed the code to pass a third argument (as false) to the `checked()` function to make sure the result is not echoed but returned instead. Props to @toscho who pointed that out in a comment to the question itself.

Comment: @toscho Ok so I have to put `checked("on", '%3$s', false)` in the params of the printf method that I can use it like I want? It will not work if I add false in my example at the top ? Thank you to all of you!

Comment: You can't put a function in the string that printf is using, it still won't understand what you're passing because printf hasn't ran before the checked function has ran.  The final variable/string must be ready for placement by the time printf runs.